# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

please tell me how solve it is

```
product.action.js
```

```
import axios from '../helpers/axios';

export const getProductsBySlug = (slug) => {
    
    return async dispatch =>{
        const res = await axios.get(`/products/${slug}`);
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

```
productListPage
```

```
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxmbI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxmbI.png)

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductsBySlug } from "../../actions";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";

/**
 * @author
 * @function ProductListPage
 **/

export const ProductListPage = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { match } = props;
    dispatch(getProductsBySlug(match.params.slug));
  }, []);

  return <Layout>Product List Page</Layout>;
};
```

i do not understand what is the issue So I'm having an error message - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Comment: Can you post the code where you are redirecting to the `ProductListPage` component?

Comment: How do you pass `props` to the `productListPage`?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting extra check and dispatch when slug becomes available

```
export const ProductListPage = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { match } = props;

  const slug = match?.params?.slug

  useEffect(() => {

    if (slug) {
      dispatch(getProductsBySlug(slug));
    }   
    
  }, [slug]);

  return <Layout>Product List Page</Layout>;
};
```

Hope it helps